# How to navigate from one tab deep into another tab?

Tags: react-navigation

Here is my React-Navigation structure

```
RootNav -> StackNavigator / mode: 'modal'
  Login -> StackNavigator
  Main -> DrawerNavigator
      Tabs -> TabNavigator
        BulletinTab -> StackNavigator
        ChatTab -> StackNavigator
          ChatList -> Screen
          ChatRoom -> Screen
        DirectoryTab -> StackNavigator 
          OrgList -> Screen 
          DirectoryList -> Screen
  ComposeNewChat -> Screen
  Settings -> StackNavigator
  ...
```

Desired navigation flow:

- The `DirectoryList` is a list of all the user user in my app. If I click on a user, it should push a a `ChatRoom` screen (transitioning in from the right). 
  When I hit the back button on the `ChatRoom` screen, I want to be taken back to `ChatList` and NOT to the DiectoryList. The `ChatRoom` should transtion out from right to left.

I have tried to:

- Reset to `ChatList` and then navigate to `ChatRoom`, but this feels janky as the current screen `DirectoryList` is replaced with `ChatList` before I navigate to `ChatList`
- Push ChatRoom to the DirectoryTab stack. Reset to `ChatList` when you hit the back button on the `ChatRoom`. However, there is no transition out animation if I do this.

Do you know how I can achieve the desired flow/transitions with my current navigation structure? If not, can you suggest another navigation structure?